# Undefined index in $_POST

Tags: php, api, http-post, postman

I am using postman to post data to very small php script. When I am trying to dump $_POST, its having some data but it gives me error when I am trying to access the variable in $_POST.

**PHP Script**

```
<?php
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
  var_dump($_POST);
  $txt = $_POST['result'];
 ?>
```

**Raw Input in Postman**

```
{"result":"sfd"}
```

**Output**

```
array(1) { ["{"result":"sfd"} "]=> string(0) "" } 
Notice: Undefined index: result in C:\xampp\htdocs\apis\index.php on line 4
```

Whats happening here?

Comment: Seems like you send wrong data from PostMan.
var_dump($_POST); - like associative array with key `"{"result":"sfd"} "` and value as empty string.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting a JSON string in arrey it can't be accessed like that first you have to decode it

like

**as Array**

```
$result = json_decode($_POST, true)
$txt = $result['result']; // text
```

**as Object**

```
$result = json_decode($_POST)
$txt = $result->result; // text
```

> **suggestion**

if your making request through jQuery `ajax`, i think you are using `JSON.stringify()` OR similar method to convert to string so instead of using `JSON.stringify()` just post as it is. so in this case you no need to using `json_decode()`.

**For example**

```
var data = {"result":"sfd"};

// data = JSON.stringify(data); // don't use this

$.ajax({
    url : url,
    data : data,
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in a json format, you need to decode it in order to access to this index.

```
<?php
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
  var_dump($_POST);
  $result = json_decode($_POST, true)
  $txt = $result['result'];
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

use [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function check

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    if(isset($_POST['result'])){
        $txt = $_POST['result'];
    }
 ?>
```